# Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated

Tags: node.js, git, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the source control feature of Windows Azure Mobile Services to push custom API scripts.

What I did:

1. Cloned the git repository. (It contained a bunch of directories with readme.md files explaining what goes where, and some config files for existing tables' permissions.)
2. Added `service/api/test.js` and `service/api/test.json` files (custom API script and config).
3. Committed and pushed changes to remote.

I got the following output from git:

```
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '1cbfbd5ac1'.
remote: Running custom deployment command...
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository\service' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts'
remote: Copying file: 'api\test.js'
remote: Copying file: 'api\test.json'
remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24.
remote: Selected node.js version 0.10.24. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
remote: npm WARN package.json myservice@1.0.0 No repository field.
remote: npm WARN package.json myservice@1.0.0 No README data
remote: Finished successfully.
remote: Deployment successful.
```

Now when I try to access any of the existing tables through the standard API (e.g. posting to `https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/tables/MyTable`), I get back a 500 Internal Server Error.

I think this line in the above output has something to do with it:

`remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated`

However, there was never any `server.js` or `app.js` included in the git repo and I have no idea what those files should contain as there appears to be no mention of these files in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this error message is **not** the culprit:

```
remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
```

Like a good programmer, I had placed configuration information in `<PROJECT_ROOT>/shared/config.json`. When I checked the log, it complained about a route not being configured properly. The documentation implies that only the `<PROJECT_ROOT>/api` contains custom routes, so I don't know why it interprets JSON files in the shared directory as route configuration when the documentation clearly states that the shared directory is specifically for shared code used by table and custom API scripts.

After changing it from `config.json` to `config.js` and making the necessary code changes, it all started working again.

I still get the warning about missing server.js/app.js files, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

**Conclusion:** Don't add JSON files to Azure Mobile Services scripts other than as specified in the `readme.md` files initially bundled with the scripts.